# Как описать обработку однотипных событий для нескольких Button?

Tags: java, android

Допустим,у меня есть такой код:

```
Button button1;
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        View.OnClickListener oclbut1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {}

        };
        button1.setOnClickListener(oclbut1);
```

И так для четырех кнопок.Как более компактно обработать нажатие для нескольких `Button` ?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только вам, но и окружающим.

Comment: имплементировать интерфейс слушателя в активити, переопределить общий для активити метод `onClick()` и определять конкретный клик по ID виджета, передаваемого аргументом в метод?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity
                  implements OnClickListener {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

 final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
 final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
 button3.setOnClickListener(this);
 button4.setOnClickListener(this);

 }   

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 switch (v.getId()) {
      case  R.id.button1:// Определяем ID элемента
      //обрабатываем событие
      break;
      case  R.id.button2:
      ...
      break;
      case  R.id.button3:
      ...
      break;
      case  R.id.button4:
      ...
      break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: напишите в коде еще имплементацию интерфейса в класс активити, это важная часть кода.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за подсказку, поправил